# Javascript: Is there a way for a point to see the background color?

Tags: javascript

Javascript: Is there a way for a point to see the background color?

I'm trying to make the color of a drawn point relate to what is on the background page.

I'm new, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What point? Share code please

Comment: Is there any chance that the "mix-blend-mode" CSS property might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt understand, maybe you want something like this.
check color is dark or light.
function will return white if dark color passed and black if light color passed..

```js
function getColorFunc(x) {
    if (!x) { return ''; }
    return (parseInt(x.replace('#', ''), 16) > 0xffffff / 2) ? '#000' : '#fff';
}

 

// will return White color
console.log( getColorFunc("ffffff") )

// will return Black color
console.log( getColorFunc("000000") )
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have enough to proceed.